# SharePoint 2013 JSOM check if a list exists in a given subsite.

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am iterating through subsites\subwebs to see if a particular list exists in every subsite. The issue I am facing is that, if a list does not exist in one subsite the whole script stops from processing further with error:-
Request failed. List 'Documents' does not exist at site with URL 'https://sharepoint.com/teams/MySite/Myweb'

What I was trying is to get away with this error and script should continue looking at next subsite. So I used Try catch, thinking that it would continue processing. But no luck. And seems like there is no direct way to check in JSOM equivalent to "tryGetList"in server obj model. Any ideas how to get away with this issue in JSOM?

Below is my script Snippet that halts as soon as it doesn't find a list in a subsite.

```
context.executeQueryAsync(
          Function.createDelegate(this, function (sender, args) {
                 listItemsCollection = [];
              for (var x = 0; x < webSubSites.get_count(); x++) {
                  var subWeb = webSubSites.itemAt(x); 
                  try{                          
                      var spListobj = subWeb.get_lists().getByTitle('Documents');
                  }
                  catch (err){  //Script breaks at this line for a subsite that dosent has Documents library.
                      alert(subWeb.get_title());
                      return false;
                  }
                      var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
                      camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query></Query></View>');
                      var spListobjItems = spListobj.getItems(camlQuery);

                      var itemDetails = new Object;
                      itemDetails.ListItems = spListobjItems;
                      listItemsCollection.push(itemDetails);
                      context.load(spListobjItems, 'Include(File)');  


                }//end for
```

Thanks,

Comment: Why do you make a return of "false" on error? That will escape the whole method

Comment: I removed "return false" and tested the issue still exists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe your code has one fundamental flaw. Since JSOM is an **async** API, you cant perform this kind of checking since list objects have to be requested first and only then in the success handler of `SP.ClientContext.executeQueryAsync` method to perform checking.

I strongly encourage you to read an article [Asynchronous programming in apps for Office](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220067%28v=office.15%29.aspx) to get acquainted with asynchronous programming concepts and patterns.

---

CSOM/JSOM API does not contains "built-in" method to determine whether list exists or not, but you could use the following approach.

The solution is to load Web object with lists collection and then iterate through list collection to find a specific list:

```
context.load(subWebs, 'Include(Title,Lists)');
```

The following example demonstrates how to iterate web sites and find specific list:

```
function findLists(listTitle)
{
   var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   var web = context.get_web(); 
   var site = context.get_site();
   var rootWeb = site.get_rootWeb();
   var subWebs = rootWeb.get_webs();

   context.load(subWebs, 'Include(Title,Lists)');
   context.executeQueryAsync(
    function () {  
         for (var i = 0; i < subWebs.get_count(); i++) {
            var subWeb = subWebs.itemAt(i);
            var lists = subWeb.get_lists();
            if(get_listExists(lists,listTitle)) { //Lists property is initialized 
               console.log(subWeb.get_title());
            }
         }
    },
    function (sender, args) {
       console.log(args.get_message());
    }
   );   
}



function get_listExists(lists,listTitle)
{
    var listExists = false;
    var le = lists.getEnumerator();
    while (le.moveNext()) {
         var list = le.get_current();
            if(list.get_title() == listTitle) {
              listExists = true;
              break;
         }
    }
    return listExists;
}



//Usage
findLists('Documents');
```

Comment: Clever, didn't think of that :)

Comment: Thanks very much!! That really helped. I will go through the asynch programming concepts.

Answer (score 5):

I think maybe the right way is to use the `SP.ExceptionHandlingScope`

Here is a simple example:

```
    function checkIfDocumentLibExists() {

       var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
       var web = context.get_web();

        try {

           var scope = new SP.ExceptionHandlingScope(context);
            var scopeStart = scope.startScope();

                var scopeTry = scope.startTry();
                    var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("Documents");
                    context.load(list);
                scopeTry.dispose();

                var scopeCatch = scope.startCatch();

                    console.log("Catch: Could create list here");

                scopeCatch.dispose();

                var scopeFinally = scope.startFinally();
                    console.log("Finnaly: Try and load the list again if created in catch");
                scopeFinally.dispose();           

            scopeStart.dispose()


            context.executeQueryAsync(function() {
                if (scope.get_hasException() == true) {
                    console.log("Does not exists")
                }
                else {
                    console.log("Exists");
                }
            }, function() {  });
        }
        catch (ex) {
            console.log(ex.message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: An interesting idea

Comment: Yes, looks to be good idea will try this sometime.

Answer (score 0):

ScopeHandling in a good way. Here's an alternate way to do recursive call for all sub webs and sub sub webs.

```
var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = context.get_web();
var rootWeb = context.get_site().get_rootWeb();

context.load(rootWeb);
context.executeQueryAsync(
   function () {
      var docLibrary = rootWeb.get_lists().getByTitle('Documents');
      if (docLibrary) {
          window.console && console.log("Root Web Contains Documents Lib: Title: " + rootWeb.get_title());
      }
   },
   function (sender, args) {
       window.console && console.log('Request failed: ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
   }
);

getSubWebs(web);

function getSubWebs(web) {

    var subWebs = web.getSubwebsForCurrentUser(null);

    context.load(subWebs);
    context.executeQueryAsync(
        function () {
            var webEnumerator = subWebs.getEnumerator();

            while (webEnumerator.moveNext()) {

                var oWeb = webEnumerator.get_current();

                var obj = {
                    title: oWeb.get_title(),
                    url: oWeb.get_serverRelativeUrl()
                };

                var docLibrary = oWeb.get_lists().getByTitle('Documents');
                if (docLibrary) {
                    window.console && console.log("Contains Documents Lib: Title: " + obj.title + " , Url: " + obj.url);
                }

                //Recursive Call
                getSubWebs(oWeb);
            }
        },
        function (sender, args) {
            window.console && console.log('Request failed: ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
        }
    );
}
```